# Why an external USB SSD drive light is blinking after ejecting it in Linux?

Tags: linux, ssd, external-hard-drive, external-drive

I am running MX Linux 19.2 (Debian 10) with KDE desktop manager.

Normally, after I eject this SSD drive, the light will be off.

But today, I noticed that the light keeps blinking after I ejected successfully.

I eject it so that there is no such drive can be found in the linux system. I tried to run `df` and `gio mount -li` and `cat /proc/partitions/`. The drive is gone and not listed at all.

But the light just keeps blinking forever. (Well, not really forever, because I can not wait forever. I wait for about 15 minutes and it is still blinking. So I unplugged it by force).

I am wondering why is it blinking. What's going on? What can I do to stop the blinking in Linux OS? Since it's not listed and shown in my OS, I doubt I might do anything about it.

PS: After I unplugged the SSD USB drive by force. I tried to plug it in again, mount it, write to it and then eject it. I did this multiple times. The light just stops blinking after ejecting it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: So did this problem occur only once?

Comment: @CrispyCon Thanks for your reply. I used this SSD USB drive on Macbook normally. This is the first time I used on Linux. In the question description, I have said that I tried multiple times today. The problem only happens at the first time. So it occurs only once today so far. And to be serious, I haven't paid too much attention on this light blinking before. From my memory, the problem didn't happen in the past. But I can't be sure. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, its not the drive that is blinking the LED, it is the drive controller board that is blinking the LED.  Even though you ejected the device, it is still receiving power by USB.  My suspicion is that the drive controller was ejected, but didnt properly shut itself down in a normal fashion and was stuck in an abnormal state.  When you unplugged it and replugged it, that abnormal state was cleared.  I wouldnt worry about it.  The only thing you might want to do is check the manufacturer of the device and drive for a firmware update, as it could be a known issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can I clear the abnormal state without unplugging it somehow with Linux commands after ejecting?

Comment: @sgon00 No, as once it ejected, you cannot intereact with the device until it is reconnected.